# check if multimethod have a particular dispatch in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a multimethod:

```
(defmulti foo type)
(defmethod foo clojure.lang.Keyword [k] (name k))
```

I would like to know if something like this is possible:

```
(valid-dispatch? foo clojure.lang.Keyword)
;;=> true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know if there is a method for *precisely* the given dispatch value:

```
(contains? (methods foo) clojure.lang.Keyword)
```

If you want to know if there is a method matching the given dispatch value (taking into account the hierarchy used by the multimethod):

```
(get-method foo clojure.lang.Keyword)
```

The latter returns the actual method if available, `nil` otherwise.